# Get current page's taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I've got some pages with a custom taxonomy for each page and i'm trying to retrieve this taxonomy on the page. I'd basically need something like `the_current_taxonomy()` like `the_title()`. This has to run outside the loop cos i'll use it in a custom `WP_Query` right after.

Edit: Found a solution using a different way to retrieve the information i needed. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i needed to extract the **term** of a know **taxonomy** given to a page (like this:

```
function register_prod_categoria() {
  register_taxonomy(
     'prod-categoria',
     array( 'produtos', 'page' ),
```

(**produtos** being a custom post type, just for info.)).

I tried various things, among them, this: `get_terms('prod-categoria','')` This, works, but gives me everything about my taxonomy **prod-categoria**, which isn't what i needed.

Then as explained in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms), two (interesting for me) parameters are available for `get_terms()`: **child_of** and **parent**. This sounded perfect, so i went: `get_terms('prod-categoria','child_of=marca');` and also `get_terms('prod-categoria','parent=marca')`, **marca** being a term parent (from the custom taxonomy ***prod-categoria***) from which i wanted to extract the child terms. Both gave me no results. I also tried with the name ***Marca*** and the slug ***marca***, nothing.

The solution i ended up with is this: `$tt = the_title('','',false);`. I'm getting the page title to use it as a parameter after: `$posts = posts_search ('produtos',array('prod-categoria'=>$tt,'prod-cols'=>'5-C-P-F-NF-P')); if($posts) { echo "<table class=\"table-marca\">"; foreach($posts as $post) { ... }`

Btw, the function posts_search() (found it on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com or http://stackoverflow.com if i'm right, don't remember for sure) allows to do queries on multiple taxonomies.

I agree very much that it's far away from being perfect, the title of the page having to be equal to the taxonomy name, but in my case it works. Thanks a lot to Rarst and Piet for trying to help.

Answer (score 7):

Like Rarst, I am confused what you want to output, the taxonomy or the terms of that taxonomy.

Taxonomy can be output for example if you make a template file with the name of that taxonomy: taxonomy-name.php

the title of the taxonomy then becomes:

```
<h1 class="page-title"><<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); echo $term->name; ?></h1>
```

The terms within a taxonomy can be output with a tagcloud, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud (but that is within the loop)

Comment: The objective is to output the term from a taxonomy allocated to the current page. So i tried to echo the terms within my taxonomy with wp_tag_cloud() and it worked, i can see the one i need to output in the middle. Then i tried to use the get_term_by() function you gave me but with no success.

Comment: I also tried to change the second parameter to $post->ID as shown in the http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by#Examples example on the codex page, but no success either.

Answer (score 3):

I assume `taxonomy` is the same and what you need are `terms` in that taxonomy, assigned to the post?

Low level function for this is [`wp_get_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms). It does need object's ID so if you are resetting post data then you will need to store that from earlier or dig out of original query (`$wp_query->get_queried_object_id()` as far as I remember).

Comment: Yes as i wrote in a comment above, i need to extract a term from a taxonomy assigned to the page to then use it as a parameter in my new WP_Query(). The problem of wp get object terms() is that is requires a taxonomy as a parameter.

Comment: @kevin  I assume if it's your own custom taxonomy you know what it is to use as parameter? Or you want all terms in all taxonomies assigned to the post? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes it's my own, but i explained myself pretty bad, i wanted to find the term allowed to a certain taxonomy that i know which is also related to the page. Sorry for not being so clear.

Comment: @kevin I still don't get it... please update your question with some specific example of what exactly you have and what you want to retrieve

Comment: @Rarst, problem solved, i edited my first post.

Comment: @kevin if you don't mind - could you please add solution you ended up with as an answer so others can benefit from it in the future.

Comment: @Rarst, done; Edit2.

Comment: @kevin as an **answer** please :) That is how system works - question and details separately, competing answers separately, even if you are answering your own question. That way there is less confusion, if someone offers improved version of code and such.

Comment: Sure thing, sorry about that, didnt know. Edit: gotta wait 3 minutes.

Comment: @Rarst, all done.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already on the category/term page you can call `get_queried_object();` before running your custom query to get category/term info, including slug.