# How to get taxonomy term of the current page and populate queries in the template

Tags: taxonomy, page-template

I've been stumbling around trying to figure out how to get a specific taxonomy term of the current page so that I can subsequently populate queries on the page for other post types that share the same term.

Basically:

- Page 1 has taxonomy term - education policy
- page.php has four parts:

  1. standard loop that outputs the page, but then has three subsequent queries
  2. loop for events that have taxonomy term - education policy
  3. loop for reports that have taxonomy term - education policy
  4. loop for people that have taxonomy term - education policy

I did page specific templates where I could just hardcode the term into the extra loops, but I need to figure out how to do it dynamically (what was originally supposed to be four or five pages is now forty or fifty).

I've found a few similar questions, but none that I could really find my way through implementing.

[Get current page's taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6389/get-current-pages-taxonomy)
which was a little confusing to follow in terms of what was actually being asked.

[Get the term id belonging to custom taxonomy on a custom single-post-type.php template page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19962/get-the-term-id-belonging-to-custom-taxonomy-on-a-custom-single-post-type-php-tem)

I hope this makes sense and many thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Hm, if you registered a taxonomy for the "page" object type correctly and then assigned a term of that taxonomy to a page... I believe you can then access the taxonomy and term slugs in the following way:

```
get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )
get_query_var( 'term' )
```

If you `print_r($wp_query)` you will see all the parameters that are there when generating a current page that's displayed. With code above you're accessing those parameters from `$wp_query`.

Then to get the term object with full info you can use [get_term_by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) function, like so

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
echo $term->name;
```

This will print the "nice" name of the term.

I believe if you use `get_query_var('term')` or `$term->slug` (after getting the term object) you can use that slug in all of other queries.

Hope that helps. I never used taxonomy for pages.
Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 4):

**Just copy paste below code**

This will print your current page taxonomy name & description (optional)

```
<?php 
   $tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
   echo ''. $tax->name . '';
   echo "<br>";
   echo ''. $tax->description .''; 
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

May be you need to enable search to enable pagination

While declaring custom taxonomy you should disable search excluding.

> exclude_from_search => false

This fixed my problem.